# What is wrong in my code...Remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, linked-list

**Remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list**

Given an unsorted linked list of `N` nodes. The task is to remove duplicate elements from this unsorted Linked List. When a value appears in multiple nodes, the node which appeared first should be kept, all others duplicates are to be removed.

**Example 1:**

**Input:**

N = 4

value[ ] = {5,2,2,4}

**Output:**  5 2 4

**Example 2:**

**Input**:

N = 5

value[] = {2,2,2,2,2}

**Output:**  2

**My Code**

```
def removeDuplicates(head):
        if head is None or not head.next:
            return head
        d = {}
        curr = head
        prev = None
        
        while curr.next:
            
            prev = curr
            curr = curr.next
            if curr.data in d:
                prev.next = curr.next
            else:
                d[curr.data] = 1
        return head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop as condition you need `curr` instead of `curr.next`. And you need to overwrite `curr` at the end of the while loop. Like this:

```
def removeDuplicates(head):
    if head is None or not head.next:
        return head
    d = {}
    curr = head
    prev = None
    while curr:
        if curr.data in d:
            prev.next = curr.next
        else:
            d[curr.data] = 1
            prev = curr
        curr = curr.next
    return head
```